# Fake proof: there are no highest weights for representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, fake-proofs, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\pi$ be a representation a $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$. Let $v$ be a highest weight vector, with $\Lambda$ the highest weight.
Then we must have $\pi(H)\pi(E^+)v=0$. But $\pi(H)$ has zero kernel, meaning that $\pi(E^+)v=0$. Since $\pi(E^+)$ also has zero kernel, $v=0$.

So this seems to show that there cannot be a highest weight vector. Of course this is wrong, and probably for a very silly reason, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The raising operator in a finite-dimensional repn certain has non-trivial kernel...

Comment: @paulgarrett But don't we demand that $\pi(X)$ is invertible for any $X$?

Comment: I don't think we require that $\pi(X)$ is invertible for all $X$... because, for example, it's impossible. :)

Comment: Maybe you are mixing up Lie algebra representations with group representations (that happened to me a lot when I began studying this). The latter can indeed be viewed as homomorphisms $\pi:G\rightarrow Aut(V)$, i.e. all $\pi(g)$ are invertible linear maps; but Lie algebra representations are morphisms $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow End(V)$ and in general, $\pi(X)$ will not be invertible for many $X\in \mathfrak{g}$. Like, as Paul Garrett says, $\pi(E^+)$ in your example.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That's exactly it, thank you!

Comment: @Soap It's also good to view group representations as monoid homomorphisms $\pi: G \to \operatorname{End}(V)$, i.e. we have $\pi(\operatorname{id}) = \operatorname{id}$ and $\pi(xy) = \pi(x) \pi(y)$. The fact that $G$ is a group forces each $\pi(x)$ to be invertible.